# Node js execute another function after complete multiple function in loop node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My code is below-:

```
function get_btc(address) {
    address_transaction(address, user_id, coin_key, deposite_txn_fee, function (callback) {
        for (var j = 0; j < callback.response.data.txs.length; j++) {
            let user_id = callback.user_id;
            //some code//
        }
    });
}

get_label_info(function (err, data) {
    var promise = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let address = data[i].address;
        var test_function = function (done) {
            deposite_model.get_coin_info(function (err, data1) {
                var coin_name = data1[0].coin_code;
                const return_functions = get_switch(coin_name);
                if (return_functions) {
                    obj[return_functions](address);
                }
                done(err, data1);
            });
        };
        promise.push(test_function);
    }
    sample();
});

function sample() {
    console.log('all functions has been completed');
}
```

By the help of above mentioned code i want to excecute all_completed loop when all functions has been completly done.
At the initial start get_label_info function is excuted then controller go on to get_btc function.

Please help me how could i run all_completed functions after all functions completed run.

Comment: you are only pushing a single function into the promise array, as the .push is outside of the loop.

Comment: note: double spaced code with poor indentation doesn't help

Comment: @Noface - no it isn't - it's just lazy indentation

Comment: `then controller go on to get_btc function` - no, you don't call get_btc *anywhere* in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Define test_function outside for loop, It's not the good approach to declare inside the loop.

```
var test_function = function (address) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        deposite_model.get_coin_info(function (err, data1) {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            var coin_name = data1[0].coin_code;
            const return_functions = get_switch(coin_name);
            if (return_functions) {
                obj[return_functions](address);
            }
            return resolve(data1);
        })
    })
}

get_label_info(function (err, data) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        promises.push(test_function(address));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
        sample();
    })
});


function sample() {
    console.log('all functions has been completed');
}
```

Comment: its works  but what happen when controll go into  get_btc function

Comment: It depends on get_btc content If there is no async call inside that no issue.

Comment: var obj = 
{
    get_btc: function get_btc(address) {

        return new Promise((resolve2,reject2) =>{

       address_transaction(address,function(callback){  

        for(var j=0; j<callback.response.data.txs.length;j++)
        {
            let data_address=callback.address;
            cron_model.is_address_exist(address,function(err,data){ 
         if(err){
                throw err;
             }  else{
                console.log('Alerady exist');             
             }
       return resolve2(data);
       })
       
       }
    });
    });
   },
}

Comment: var  test_function =  function(address,user_id,coin_key){

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{

    deposite_model.get_coin_info(user_id,coin_key,function(err,data1){

    if(err){
        return reject(err);
    }
    var promises1=[];

     var coin_name=data1[0].coin_code;
        
     const return_functions = get_switch(coin_name);

    if (return_functions) {

        promises1.push(obj[return_functions](address));
        };

        Promise.all(promises1).then((data)=>{

          resolve(data1);
       });

    })
   })        
}

Comment: cron_model.get_label_info(function(err,data){

    if(err){

        throw err;

    }else{
        var promises=[];
    for (var i=0;i<data.length; i++) {
        let address=data[i].address;
        let user_id=data[i].user_id;   
        let coin_key=data[i].coin_key;
        promises.push(test_function(address,user_id,coin_key));     
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then((data)=>{
          sample();
    });

    }
});

function sample() {
    console.log('all functions has been completed');
}

Comment: @RiyaSinghal In get_btc function, you are resolving promise inside the loop, It'll resolve only one time, not for each iteration.

Comment: but rahul with this code i am getting 'already exist' msg on console. and not executing of sample function. could u please help me out? what is happening here.

Comment: Promise returns result(resolves) only one time, but your function executing after that also. make that function also promise and use inside `Promise.all()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167140/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-riya-singhal).